# How to return http respons from node.js function when it depends on async javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

My aws lambda function(nodejs v16) is based on one from the aws blog post bellow.
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/signed-cookie-based-authentication-with-amazon-cloudfront-and-aws-lambdaedge-part-1-authentication/

At the bottom of the code from the aws blog, the authors write as follows, where the comments are by me.

```
   await sendEmail(publicKey, privateKey, email); //sending email through aws ses
   return response; //http response
```

For my version, I want to give some changes so that the flow switches when returning http response with two cases where one is for success of sendEmail and the other is for error.

Though for me it seems a kind of puzzle to make it work so. Please give me some skeleton solution. I think it is a problem of async, await, then and promise.

Here follows my version of sendEmail.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
const nodeMailer = require("nodemailer")
exports.sendMail = async(from, to, totp6) => {
  
   const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
     host: "smtp.host.com",
     secure: true,
     port: 465,
     auth: {
       user: "user",
       pass: "pass",
     },
   });
   const mailOptions = {
      from: from, // sender address
      to: to,
      subject: "subject", // Subject line
      html: `<p>Your passcode is 123455.</p>`, // plain text body
     };
     return await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
        if (err) { 
           return "Error, Please try again."//I guess I'm wrong here.
         }else{
            return "OK, Please check the passcode in the mail." //I guess I'm wrong here.
         }
     })
 　}
/*
and I want use the code above as follows

const ok = await sendEmail("from","to","123456")
if(ok){return ok_response}
else{return err_response }
*/
```

Here follows the whole original code from the aws blog.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ses = new AWS.SES({ region: '<your-region>' });
const ssm = new AWS.SSM({ region: '<your-region>' });

// Either defined as a constant or retrieved from AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store
const SENDER = '<your-sender-email-address>';

// Either defined as a constant or retrieved from AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store
const SIGNING_URL = '<your-cloudfront-url>';

const signingUrl = `https://${SIGNING_URL}/auth`;

const content = `
<\!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Successful request</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Email with authentication token sent</p>
  </body>
</html>
`;

const response = {
    status: '200',
    statusDescription: 'OK',
    headers: {
        'cache-control': [{
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value: 'max-age=100'
        }],
        'content-type': [{
            key: 'Content-Type',
            value: 'text/html'
        }]
    },
    body: content,
};

const error = {
    body: 'Email is not valid',
    bodyEncoding: 'text',
    headers: {
        'content-type': [{
            key: 'Content-Type',
            value: 'text/html'
        }]
    },
    status: '204',
    statusDescription: 'Error'
};

const cache = {}

const loadParameter = async(key, withDecryption = false) => {
    const { Parameter } = await ssm.getParameter({ Name: key, WithDecryption: withDecryption }).promise();
    return Parameter.Value;
};

const validateEmail = (allowedDomains, email) => {
    if (!allowedDomains) return false;
    const re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email) && allowedDomains.indexOf(email.substring(email.indexOf("@"))) >= 0;
};

const sendEmail = async(publicKey, privateKey, email) => {
    const cloudFront = new AWS.CloudFront.Signer(publicKey, privateKey);
    const signedUrl = cloudFront.getSignedUrl({
        url: signingUrl,
        expires: Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 1) // Current Time in UTC + time in seconds, (60 * 60 * 1 = 1 hour)
    });

    const params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [
                email
            ]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Html: {
                    Data: signedUrl,
                    Charset: 'UTF-8'
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: '[stars on AWS] Login credentials for ' + email,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
        },
        Source: SENDER
    };
    await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
};

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    if (cache.allowedDomains == null) cache.allowedDomains = loadParameter('allowedDomains')
    if (cache.publicKey == null) cache.publicKey = loadParameter('publicKey');
    if (cache.privateKey == null) cache.privateKey = loadParameter('privateKey', true);

    const { allowedDomains, publicKey, privateKey } = cache;

    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    if (request.method === 'GET') {
        const parameters = new URLSearchParams(request.querystring);
        if (parameters.has('email') === false) return error;
        const email = parameters.get('email');
        if (!validateEmail(allowedDomains, email)) return error;
        else {
            await sendEmail(publicKey, privateKey, email);
            return response;
        }
    }
    return error;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
await sendEmail(publicKey, privateKey, email).then(()=>{ 
  return response;
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck